# Combinations and Permutations of Painting a Fence

Tags: combinatorics

*Tom Sawyer is painting a straight fence made of ten wooden stakes. He has three colors of paint: red, white, and blue. Each stake must be painted in one of the colors.*

1. In how many ways can he paint the fence if there are no restrictions on its coloring?
2. What if he wants no two consecutive stakes to be the same color?
3. What if he wants every three consecutive stakes to be different colors?

For 1, I got 3^10. I need guidance on 2. For 3 I also would like guidance. This was under a "Beginner to Combinations and Permutations" worksheet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For b, how many choices does he have for the first stake?  Given that choice, how many choices does he have for the second stake? Given that, how many choices for the third?  And so on.

For c, repeat the reasoning, you will get different numbers for some of it.

Comment: Ah I see for b. 3 for the first stake, then 2,then 2's to the end, so for b: 3 * 2^9, and for c: 3 * 2 * 1 * 1... = 6?

Comment: @Spaazmaster. Exactly!